# How to access returned object from different function & class

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

I have a c# application where once you press the button it will send a web request to a web API and retrieve all the Json values. These are then deserialized into a object and returned to where the function was called.

Now I am trying to access the object that was returned from the GetApi function in another class.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'GW2_tradingPost.Listings'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) line 32

i understand I am doing it wrong, but I can not grasp *what* is going wrong.

Form1.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Listings Listings = new Listings();
        api_Request api_Request = new api_Request();

        Listings richTextBox1 = api_Request.GetApi("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/19684");
    }
```

api_Request.cs

```
public class api_Request
    {
        public Object GetApi(string url)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    //return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    return serializer.Deserialize<Listings>(jsonReader);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // log errorText
                }
                throw;
            }
        }

    }

    public class Listings
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<Buy> Buys { get; private set; }

        public Listings()
        {
            Buys = new List<Buy>();
        }
    }
    public class Buy
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "listings")]
        public int Listings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "unit_price")]
        public int UnitPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Im using this to call upon the object now and return a value in the messagebox, but its returning 0 which should be 19684.

> api_Request.GetApi("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/19684");
>   MessageBox.Show(Listings.Id.ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature is `Object GetApi(string url)`. Change it to `Listings GetApi(string url)`, as that is what you actually return from that method.

Also consider giving the "GetApi" method a more sensible name that tells what it actually does.

Comment: Alright that makes a lot of sense to actually return the correct type. But how. But for accessing the object, how do I do that? Right now it returns the class name `Listings` as im not saying what i want to retrieve from the object.

Comment: @Krijn I'm not sure what you mean, but the class has properties you can access.

Comment: Yes I was about to respond that i got it working, sorry for that! Just some stupid syntax i keep messing up. Thanks a lot for helping me out!!