# Can't access custom class properties when returning object

Tags: c#, object, properties

I have this code which retrieves Json values from a Api link and enters them in a list. In this list there are Ids, all these ids are checked if exist in another API link.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var spidyApi_searchIdByName_result = api_Handler.GetApi(spidyApi_searchIdByName);
    var Gw2Api_isItemIdinListing_result = api_Handler.GetApi(Gw2Api_allListings + spidyApi_searchIdByName_result.???); // can't access object property      
}
```

This is the GetApi method:

```
public object GetApi(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
        }
    }

    catch (WebException)
    {       
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>("{\"text\":\"no such id\"}");
    }

}
```

This is the RootObject to which the `GetApi()` method deserializes:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

However, I can't access the returned object's properties when returning an `object` from `GetApi()`. How can I access those?

Comment: Like I told you in the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414196/c-sharp-how-to-access-returned-object-from-different-function-class), don't use `object` as return type but the actual type you _want_ to return, in that case `Listings` and in this case `RootObject`. The class `object` doesn't have the properties you want to access, but `RootObject` does.

Comment: yes i know which worked good at first, but now in the catch i return return `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>("{\"text\":\"no such id\"}");` Which will give the error that i cant convert .A to .RootObject

Comment: Because you can't return two different types from one method. Edit your question to be about that specific problem and remove all irrelevant code and text.

Comment: Return null when you catch an exception instead that thing you are creating

Comment: @Plutonix i can not return null as it expects an object.

Comment: but you can test for a null return  cant you?  I think you removed the wrong part in the edit; the issue is in GetApi

Comment: @Plutonix yes sorry that was a mistake of mine. And if i do test the value to be null, what do i do then? I still have to return a object.

Comment: No, test *the return from GetAPI* for null.  You'd get back either a valid RootObject or null because of the web exception.

Comment: i dont fully understand nor know how to do that. Is there a possibility to start a chat or answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, you're returning `object` from your method, so you can't access [any members that `object` doesn't have](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's why you should return a more specialized type [like I already advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414196/c-sharp-how-to-access-returned-object-from-different-function-class), so in this case:

```
public RootObject GetApi(string url)
{
    // ...
    return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
}
```

However, you want this method to be able to do more. You want to return two types from it and also add error handling.

Generics (see `T`) could help here, where you specifiy the type when *calling* the method:

```
public T GetObjectFromApi<T>(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {       
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var spidyApi_searchIdByName_result = api_Handler.GetObjectFromApi<spidyApiResult>(spidyApi_searchIdByName);
if (spidyApi_searchIdByName_result != null)
{
    var Gw2Api_isItemIdinListing_result = api_Handler.GetApi<RootObject>(Gw2Api_allListings + spidyApi_searchIdByName_result.someProperty);
}
```

Of course this swallows the WebException.

Comment: I dont fully understand. You call the `GetObjectFromApi` and then insert `spidyApiResult` as `T` value. What is this `spidyApiResult`? Should it be class `A`? But it also doesn't recognize `RootObject` and i cant return `null`.